# A Simple Integration Question Involving Square Roots

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

1. Let's say I have a function $f(x)$ of which I have its indefinite integral, but not the function itself. How would I find the integral of $\sqrt{f(x)}$?
2. If it is not possible, then let's say I do know what $f(x)$ is? How would I then find the integral $\sqrt{f(x)}$, knowing $f(x)$?

Comment: You would not find it.

Comment: @Gae.S. Why not?

Comment: Maybe this is "cheating" for some reason, if you know that $g(x)=\int{f(x)}$ then why can't you just take the derivative of $g(x)$, take its square root, and then integrate that?

Comment: @roundsquare Because that could be very complicated (integrating the square roots of functions are not easy).

Comment: (1) Like Greg writes in his answer, knowing $\int f(x) \,dx$ typically does not help you compute $\int \sqrt{f(x)} \,dx$. (2) I'm still not sure what this is asking exactly---once you know what $f(x)$ is, you know what $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is: By definition it's the composition of the square root function with $f(x)$.

Comment: @Travis Whoops, sorry, I meant integral of $\sqrt{f(x)}$

Comment: In general there's really not much that you can say (and in a sense you shouldn't expect there to be). Even when you can compute both integrals explicitly often they're radically different in character. For example, if $f(x) = x^2 + a^2$, then $$\int f(x) \,dx = \frac{1}{3} x^3 + a^2 x + C$$ but $$\int \sqrt{f(x)} \,dx = \frac{1}{2} \left[ x \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} + a^2 \log\left(\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} + x\right) \right] + C .$$

Comment: @Travis Ok, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: $$f(x) = x + \cos x.$$ The indefinite integral of $f(x)$ is trivial to find, but that doesn't help us find the indefinite integral of $\sqrt{f(x)}$—indeed that indefinite integral is not an elementary function.

Not all integrals can be evaluated!

Comment: How are you supposed to find it though?